# DevExpress DataBinding, Add new Record

Tags: c#, .net, windows, data-binding, devexpress

I am using DevExpress in my winform application, I have a gridview, data entry form, datanavigator, all bound to dataset.

I want to add new record, if using datanavigator "**Add**" it works good, how to do the same using a "**New Record**" button?

```
BindingSource.AddNew()
```

is not working, it usually does, but with devexpress its not working.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what doesn't work? I just created a new DX WinForms application using their wizard. I bound the grid to a new DB table. I added an event handler for a navbar item that calls BindingSource.AddNew(). When clicked, a new row is added to the grid.

Comment: this is really wired, i just restarted the pc, now everything is working fine.

Comment: Ideally you should be using some kind of model that promotes separation of concerns. Like MVVM or MVC. If you do that you will have some kind of collection - a BindingList<T> perhaps that you have bound to. If you use the BindingList<T> then just a source.Add(new T()) is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use binding then use your objects with binding source..

and use the binding list `.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(listOfParts_AddingNew);`
event to add new entity object ..

See the example of BindingList on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).

```
void listOfParts_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
        {
            e.NewObject = new Part(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));

        }
```

DevExpress WinForm Controls works so fast with binding sources as compare to typed datasources etc... YOu can implement bindingSources using these example..

set gridview and the associcated controls datasource  to bindsouce that you have created...
process your form with the this MSDN example..

have a look on this code snippet.. may be you will get some idea from this..

```
private void BindingLIstDemo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeListOfEmployees();
            BindlstEmp();
            listofEmp.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(listOfEmp_AddingNew);
            listofEmp.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(listofEmp_ListChanged);

        }

        private void BindlstEmp()
        {
            lstEmpList.Items.Clear();
            lstEmpList.DataSource = listofEmp;
            lstEmpList.DisplayMember = "Name";

        }

        void listofEmp_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ListChangedType.ToString());
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //declare list of employees
        BindingList<Emp> listofEmp;
        private void InitializeListOfEmployees()
        {

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            // Create the new BindingList of Employees.
            listofEmp = new BindingList<Emp>();

            // Allow new Employee to be added, but not removed once committed.
            listofEmp.AllowNew = true;
            listofEmp.AllowRemove = true;

            // Raise ListChanged events when new Employees are added.
            listofEmp.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

            // Do not allow Employee to be edited.
            listofEmp.AllowEdit = false;

            listofEmp.Add(new Emp(1, "Niranjan", 10000));
            listofEmp .Add (new Emp (2,"Jai", 8000));

          }


        // Create a new Employee from the text in the two text boxes.
        void listOfEmp_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
        {
            e.NewObject = new Emp (Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text), txtName.Text,Convert.ToInt32(txtSalary.Text));

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Emp empItem = listofEmp.AddNew();
            txtId.Text = txtName.Text = txtSalary.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 obj = new Form1();
            obj.Show();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sg = (from sc in listofEmp.ToList<Emp>() where sc.Name == ((Emp)lstEmpList.SelectedValue).Name select sc);





        }

        private void lstEmpList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Emp se = listofEmp[lstEmpList.SelectedIndex];
            txtId.Text = se.Id.ToString();
            txtName.Text = se.Name;
            txtSalary.Text = se.Salary.ToString();

        }
```

Here I am using `BindingList` as datasouce `BindingList<Emp> listofEmp;` and on the place of grid listing of records are shown in a listbox control.. but all same...try this with your gridview..